# How to access Solr UI from on network

Tags: solr

I created my own core and added some XML files so I can search on the http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore/browse on my own computer. But I've been thinking about how to let others access this Sole UI and can search these documents from their computers too, that is to say, how to access it from an external IP address?
I've gone through the related questions on stackoverflow , but it seems I got more confused about this question.
Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the cmd ,use ipconfig to know your ip address , after u start solr in your computer , then in the other computer use  http://:8983/solr/mycore/browse    to browse the UI.

Comment: thx a lot!  BTW, do you know if there is any SVD-like class in solr/lucene? I want to enhance my search results but have no clues.  From my research only mahout could do it. Am I right?